# How to configure an XML file with a dropdown menu

Tags: lightning-web-components, xml, digital-experience

I'm trying to recreate a LWC. I want to receive the values from the little popup menu on the digital experience page in my LWC and to format it like this:

[image]

I'm not sure how I would get the dropdown to work under target configs on a lightning community page. My code just looks like this right now

```
    <targets>
        <target>lightningCommunity__Page</target>
        <target>lightningCommunity__Default</target>
        <target>lightning__RecordAction</target>
        <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
        <!-- <target>lightningCommunity__Default</target> -->
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightningCommunity__Default">
            <property name="header" type="String" default="My Settings" label="User Settings Header"/>
            <property name="recordid" type="String" default="{!recordId}" label="User ID"/>>
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code -

```
<property label="Name" name="name" type="String" datasource="value1,value2,value3" default="value1"/>
```

Renders a field as a picklist, with static values. Supported only if the type attribute is String.

Not works for lightning__FlowScreen